# WIFI handover between AP with same SSID on different channels

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat

Using devices (Zebra Mobile [TC25](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/solutions-verticals/product/Mobile_Computers/Hand-Held%20Computers/tc25-smartphone/spec-sheet/tc25-specification-sheet-a4.pdf)) running Android 7, I am having problems with the WIFI handover not happening.
The situation is that I have several access points set up with the same SSID but broadcasting on different channels.

As I walk around I would expect that the WIFI would connect to the strongest boradcasting AP. This is not happening.

Is this a consequence of the APs having the same SSID? Is it something to do with once a connection is established Android OS is not keen to switch even if SSID has same name, irrespective of signal strength?

Comment: As nearly every device manufacturer modifies the Android OS you should always include the device mane and manufacturer in your question. Regarding Wifi this may be even specific to the Wifi chip and used driver.

Comment: thanks, good point, have updated with the details you mentioned.

Comment: Looks like the Zebra TC25 supports "Wifi Fast Roaming 802.11r" - AFAIK this requires also that your Wifi network supports this protocol.

Comment: thanks will have a look into it.